# How to pass a hyphen ( - ) in an Automation Anywhere variable without being an operator?

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

AAE's "PDF Integration" command allows you to split a .pdf into a [separate single file](https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v11.3/page/topics/aae-client/bot-creator/commands/splitting-documents.html) for a selected number of pages or **range of pages** (Figure 1). The "Single File With Selected Pages" field also allows you to input a variable. But how do you create a variable with a hyphen (-) included where it doesn't see that as an [operator](https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v11.3/page/topics/aae-client/bot-creator/commands/variable-operation-command.html) instead?

The way I currently have the variable in Figure 2, AAE will see the hyphen (-) as an operator and subtract the two nested variables. I've tried putting the hyphen in parenthesis, double-quotes, single-quotes, and I can't find anything in AAE's documentation that shows how to use the hyphen as a character instead of an operator. I also tried using a dash (–), but AAE doesn't appear to recognize a dash in that field. The only area in their documentation that references a dash is in [dates](https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/iq-bot-v6.0/page/topics/iq-bot/user/bot-training-validation-date.html).

The "Single File With Selected Pages" field in the "PDF Integration" command only allows you to enter 1 variable, so that is why I'm trying to create a "range" variable that includes the start and ending pages separated by the hyphen.

**Figure 1:**

[image: Figure 1]

**Figure 2:**

[image: Figure 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Workaround:**

Using variable operations: **$start$#$end$** concatenate with any sign that's not math operation i.e **#**.

Using string operation replace the sign with **hyphen** **sign**.

Now you will have ie. 5-7 and you can use it in the **pdf split command.**